# Sort name & time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I "invented" "new" sort algorithm. Well, I understand that I can't invent something good, so I tried to search it on wikipedia, but all sort algorithms seems like not my. So I have three questions:

1. What is name of this algorithm?
2. Why it sucks? (best, average and worst time complexity)
3. Can I make it more better still using this idea?

So, idea of my algorithm: if we have an array, we can count number of sorted elements and if this number is less that half of length we can reverse array to make it more sorted. And after that we can sort first half and second half of array. In best case, we need only O(n) - if array is totally sorted in good or bad direction. I have some problems with evaluation of average and worst time complexity.

Code on C#:

```
    public static void Reverse(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        int length = end - begin;
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
            Algorithms.Swap(ref array[begin+i], ref array[begin + length - i - 1]);
    }
    public static bool ReverseIf(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        int countSorted = 1;
        for (int i = begin + 1; i < end; i++)
            if (array[i - 1] <= array[i])
                countSorted++;

        int length = end - begin;
        if (countSorted <= length/2)
            Reverse(array, begin, end);

        if (countSorted == 1 || countSorted == (end - begin))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static void ReverseSort(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        if (begin == end || begin == end + 1)
            return;
        // if we use if-operator (not while), then array {2,3,1} transforms in array {2,1,3} and algorithm stop
        while (!ReverseIf(array, begin, end)) {
            int pivot = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
            ReverseSort(array, begin, pivot + 1);
            ReverseSort(array, pivot, end);
        }
    }
    public static void ReverseSort(int[] array) {
        ReverseSort(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
```

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Comment: As little improvement we can add InsertionSort when length of part of array <= 10.

Comment: It's not identical to [Stooge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort), but it has the same flavor.

Comment: It doesn't have a name because it doesn't actually sort. Consider (3, 1, 2, 0). This flips to (0, 2, 1, 3). You split it into (0, 2) and (1, 3) and recurse. Each of the subarrays is sorted, so you're done. The resulting array is (0, 2, 1, 3), which is not sorted.

Comment: Once the two halves are in sorted order (assuming they are), how do you combine them so that the result is sorted?

Comment: @Raymond Chen The subproblems overlap by one pivot element.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't writed that in description. I check, while array is unsorted I sort halves of array. And my halfes not really halves.  When i have array begin=0,end=4 it divided in begin=0,end=3 and begin=2,end=4

Comment: @Per Oh sorry I missed the while loop. I agree that this is a less efficient variant of Stooge Sort as you noted above.

Comment: @Raymond Chen The subproblems are in a while loop that doesn't break out until the array is sorted.

Comment: So it sucks more than even stooge sort?

Comment: @nsinreal I think it's better, because of the check for a sorted array. See my answer.

Comment: At any rate, I think this belongs on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RaymondChen In future i will know that. How can I move question with answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best case is Theta(n), for, e.g., a sorted array. The worst case is Theta(n^2 log n).

**Upper bound**

*Secondary* subproblems have a sorted array preceded or succeeded by an arbitrary element. These are O(n log n). If preceded, we do O(n) work, solve a secondary subproblem on the first half and then on the second half, and then do O(n) more work – O(n log n). If succeeded, do O(n) work, sort the already sorted first half (O(n)), solve a secondary subproblem on the second half, do O(n) work, solve a secondary subproblem on the first half, sort the already sorted second half (O(n)), do O(n) work – O(n log n).

Now, in the general case, we solve two *primary* subproblems on the two halves and then slowly exchange elements over the pivot using secondary invocations. There are O(n) exchanges necessary, so a straightforward application of the Master Theorem yields a bound of O(n^2 log n).

**Lower bound**

For k >= 3, we construct an array A(k) of size 2^k recursively using the above analysis as a guide. The bad cases are the arrays [2^k + 1] + A(k).

Let A(3) = [1, ..., 8]. This sorted base case keeps `Reverse` from being called.

For k > 3, let A(k) = [2^(k-1) + A(k-1)[1], ..., 2^(k-1) + A(k-1)[2^(k-1)]] + A(k-1). Note that the primary subproblems of [2^k + 1] + A(k) are equivalent to [2^(k-1) + 1] + A(k-1).

After the primary recursive invocations, the array is [2^(k-1) + 1, ..., 2^k, 1, ..., 2^(k-1), 2^k + 1]. There are Omega(2^k) elements that have to move Omega(2^k) positions, and each of the secondary invocations that moves an element so far has O(1) sorted subproblems and thus is Omega(n log n).

---

Clearly more coffee is required – the primary subproblems don't matter. This makes it not too bad to analyze the **average case**, which is **Theta(n^2 log n)** as well.

With constant probability, the first half of the array contains at least half of the least quartile and at least half of the greatest quartile. In this case, regardless of whether `Reverse` happens, there are Omega(n) elements that have to move Omega(n) positions via secondary invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now i understand, why this algorithm doesn't described in wiki

Answer (score 1):

It seems this algorithm, even if it performs horribly with "random" data (as demonstrated by Per in their answer), is quite efficient for "fixing up" arrays which are "nearly-sorted". Thus if you chose to develop this idea further (I personally wouldn't, but if you wanted to think about it as an exercise), you would do well to focus on this strength.

[this reference on Wikipedia in the Inversion article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29#CITEREFMahmoud2000) alludes to the issue very well. Mahmoud's book is quite insightful, noting that there are various ways to measure "sortedness". For example if we use the number of inversions to characterize a "nearly-sorted array" then we can use insertion sort to sort it extremely quickly. However if your arrays are "nearly-sorted" in slightly different ways (e.g. a deck of cards which is cut or loosely shuffled) then insertion sort will not be the best sort to "fix up" the list.

- Input: an array that has already been sorted of size N, with roughly N/k inversions.

I might do something like this for an algorithm:

- Calculate number of inversions. (`O(N lg(lg(N)))`, or can assume is small and skip step)

  - If number of inversions is < [threshold], sort array using insertion sort (it will be fast).
  - Otherwise the array is not close to being sorted; resort to using your favorite comparison (or better) sorting algorithm

There are better ways to do this though; one can "fix up" such an array in at least `O(log(N)*(# new elements))` time if you preprocess your array enough or use the right data-structure, like an array with linked-list properties or similar which supports binary search.

You can generalize this idea even further. Whether "fixing up" an array will work depends on the kind of fixing-up that is required. Thus if you update these statistics whenever you add an element to the list or modify it, you can dispatch onto a good "fix-it-up" algorithm.

But unfortunately this would all be a pain to code. You might just be able to get away with want is a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).